# cp-abe public key, access structure

Tags: encryption, abe

I have three questions regarding CP-ABE:

1) Is it correct to assume that in this scheme there is only one public key? Private keys are generated based on one's attributes that I do understand, by the authority.

Previously I thought I would be able to generate one's public key based on one's attribute (identity ID for example) and encrypt data with one's public key which I generated based on recipient's ID. But now I see it was wrong thinking, you need to encrypt data with a public key, which is only one throughout the lifetime of the system, and the encryption mechanism just takes into account the values of attributes which you've specified. Is that correct?

2) If above holds true and there is only one global public key based on a global secret then I assume there's no way for message originator to sign his message under this scheme. So that a recipient could verify that the message originator is really the one in possession of a given attribute (such as Id). I'm thinking of ways of implementing authentication under this scheme.

3) If one encrypts a message under specific access structure parameter values are these values in plaintext? I mean if one encrypts a message under attribute ID value '11' is everyone else able to see who the recipient actually is? I mean are they able to read the value '11'.

Comment: Do you mean "one public key" total or "one public key" per attribute?

Comment: I mean one public key total, as I wrote "only one global public key". One public key total and multiple private keys based on one's attributes. but a single private key per attribute set. correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Is it correct to assume that in this scheme there is only one public key? Private keys are generated based on one's attributes that I do understand, by the authority.

No, each attribute is a public key. When you are encrypting a message, you form the access policy using the public keys of the various attributes needed from your policy.

> 2) If above holds true and there is only one global public key based on a global secret then I assume there's no way for message originator to sign his message under this scheme. So that a recipient could verify that the message originator is really the one in possession of a given attribute (such as Id). I'm thinking of ways of implementing authentication under this scheme.

The above does not hold true, but I wanted to comment. Researchers have developed [other primitives](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/595.pdf) for attribute based signing. There has also been research published on [attribute based signcryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/555.pdf), which combines the two.

> 3) If one encrypts a message under specific access structure parameter values are these values in plaintext? I mean if one encrypts a message under attribute ID value '11' is everyone else able to see who the recipient actually is? I mean are they able to read the value '11'.

Under the original constructs, the access policy was public. So if you got a hold of a ciphertext and the policy, you could determine what attributes are necessary for decryption. Since then, researchers have developed methods to allow you to hide or keep private certain attributes in an access policy.

Comment: thank you for addressing all of my question and pointing me these two artciles. your answer has been of tremendous help.

Comment: just one more thing. Lets say there is an attribute ID. Is is true that it is NOT required at the setup-stage to define EVERY possible value of ID? or does adding a new possibility to the space of possible ID-values require reissuance of all of the private keys related to to that atrribute.

Comment: @Vega4, this is stretching my knowledge here, but I believe that in some ABE systems you do not have to have every ID known _a priori_, but maybe just an upper bound on the number of IDs. I'll see if I can find any examples, however.

Comment: Check out section 5 of [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/vipul/abe.pdf). It talks about large-universe constructions.

Comment: I do like StackExchange and people helping out each other here vvery very much:] still reading one of the papers you've handed. ty

Comment: To add to question 3: normal non-hiding constructions usually have the group element that represents an attribute. In large universe constructions, this can be a hash from the textual representation of the attribute to the corresponding group element. Outsiders would need to compute the pre-image of that hash to find out which attributes where used. An implementation could be hardened in this case by first hashing with PBKDF2 and only then with the group-based hash. Proper hiding of attributes is usually not possible with arbitrary access structures, but with flat ones like hidden vector enc.

Comment: In a one to many file sharing application, is there a need to hide the access policy? Since it is public, I was wondering if it could be used as metadata so that receivers could query what they would be able to decrypt before downloading.